# Custom block tags failing or working inconsistently

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

In my custom map, I'm setting up a system where magic spells check to see if they can be cast in a valid block. To do this, I've setup a block tag containing all the valid blocks where spells can be cast. At first it was working great, but the more tags I added into the .json list, the more inconsistent it was in game--to the point where my list doesn't even work anymore.

Here is an example of my spell_cast_blocks.json:

```
{
  "values": [
    "#minecraft:flowers",
    "#minecraft:saplings",
    "minecraft:air",
    "minecraft:cave_air",
    "minecraft:grass",
    "minecraft:tall_grass",
    "minecraft:fire",
    "minecraft:red_mushroom",
    "minecraft:brown_mushroom",
    "minecraft:crimson_fungus",
    "minecraft:warped_fungus",
    "minecraft:small_dripleaf",
    "minecraft:big_dripleaf",
    "minecraft:fern",
    "minecraft:large_fern",
    "minecraft:sugar_cane",
    "minecraft:lily_pad",
    "minecraft:cobweb",
    "minecraft:vine",
    "minecraft:glow_lichen",
    "minecraft:hanging_roots",
    "minecraft:weeping_vines",
    "minecraft:twisting_vines",
    "minecraft:bamboo",
    "minecraft:small_amethyst_bud",
    "minecraft:medium_amethyst_bud",
    "minecraft:large_amethyst_bud",
    "minecraft:amethyst_cluster",
    "minecraft:pointed_dripstone",
    "minecraft:moss_carpet",
    "minecraft:water",
    "minecraft:kelp",
    "minecraft:seagrass",
    "minecraft:sea_pickle",
    "#minecraft:slabs",
    "#minecraft:stairs",
    "#minecraft:fences",
    "#minecraft:fence_gates",
    "#minecraft:doors",
    "#minecraft:trapdoors",
    "#minecraft:pressure_plates",
    "#minecraft:buttons",
    "minecraft:barrier",
    "minecraft:lantern",
    "minecraft:soul_lantern",
    "minecraft:lever",
    "minecraft:chain",
    "minecraft:tripwire_hook",
    "minecraft:string",
    "minecraft:torch",
    "minecraft:soul_torch",
    "minecraft:end_rod",
    "minecraft:oak_sign",
    "minecraft:birch_sign",
    "minecraft:spruce_sign",
    "minecraft:dark_oak_sign",
    "minecraft:jungle_sign",
    "minecraft:acacia_sign",
    "minecraft:mangrove_sign",
    "minecraft:crimson_sign",
    "minecraft:warped_sign"
  ]
}
```

If the spell is cast in ANY of those block types, it should allow it. Here is a snippet of code I use to summon a particle if the check passes:

```
(being executed as the player from a previous function reference)

execute if block ^ ^1.5 ^1 #sal:spell_cast_blocks run particle minecraft:poof ^ ^1.5 ^1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.01 1 normal
```

I don't get it... when I reduced the number of blocks in my spell_cast_blocks.json to 2-10, it worked fine, but the more I added the less it seems to work. Is there something I don't understand about block tags? Can you check for both individual blocks and block tag groups at the same time (e.g. minecraft:air and #minecraft:stairs)?

Comment: if just one block entry in your list doesn't exist, the whole tag fails to load. In this case, `"minecraft:string"` is not a valid block. Are you maybe thinking of `tripwire` instead? Enable the [content log when starting the game](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/734106483104415856/854123107325575188/unknown.png) and it will tell you issues such as this one when you do `/reload`